# Absolutely positioned DIV changes position when I scroll down in chrome mobile, How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

this is my app here https://scisaif.github.io/Budget-App/

CSS for the div element:

```
.add-box, .add-box-opt {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0vh;
   right: 0vw;
   width: 100px;
   min-height: 100px;
   border-top: 2px solid white;
   border-left: 2px solid white;
   border-radius: 80% 0 0 0 ;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px rgba(211, 209, 209, 0.562);
   cursor: crosshair;
   }
```

I want the div box to stay at the bottom right corner even if i scroll, this problem only happens in chrome browser in mobile. please help.

before scroll:
[before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugwUb.png)

after scroll:
[after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7fDe.png)

Comment: Set `position: fixed;`

Comment: also use : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem should be solved by using `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.

This is because `position: fixed` is relative to the viewport, while `position: absolute` is relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

Make sure to keep `bottom: 0;` and `right: 0;`.